# Angular displaying edit form with their perticular row value

Tags: angular

I have one issue. when I click on the edit button my form is not displaying a particular row value.I'm using a popup for a form that is in one component and table with edit button in another component. I'm using patchValue to edit. how to use formGroup name in other component.

here is my form.component.html file

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="userprofileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

this is my form.component.ts file

```
 userprofileForm = this.fb.group({
companyName: ['', Validators.required],
companyAddress: ['', Validators.required],
companyPhone: ['', Validators.required],
about: ['', Validators.required],
companyWebsite: [''],
```

})

this is my table.component.ts file

```
onEdit(element: any ) {
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
dialogConfig.width = "55%";
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateCompanyDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
this.getCompanyById(id);

this.user.updateCompany(element).subscribe(res => {
     console.log(element);

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
    if (data !== "") 
    {
        this.userprofileForm.setValue({
        companyName: data.companyName,
        companyAddress: data.companyAddress,
        companyPhone: data.companyPhone,
        about: data.about,
        companywebsite: data.companyWebsite

      })
    }
  })
})
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open the dialog only after getting data from the service , then pass the data to the dialog as follows

```
this.user.updateCompany(element).subscribe(res => {

const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
dialogConfig.width = "55%";

dialogConfig.data = res;
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateCompanyDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
});
```

Then in your form component you should get the passed data as

```
constructor(  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any) 
   {
    
   }

ngOnInit(){
   this.userprofileForm.setValue({
        companyName: dialogData.companyName,
        companyAddress: dialogData.companyAddress,
        companyPhone: dialogData.companyPhone,
        about: dialogData.about,
        companywebsite: dialogData.companyWebsite

      })
}
```